# Symfony2 services : list of examples?

Tags: symfony, service

I think I understand the concept of services, but I don't seem to be able to find practical, real-life examples of them, except, of course, for the mailer service. The mailer example is great, but it would really help me catch the whole thing if there were other ones. Can anyone provide me with a (short and simple) list of concrete cases where you should use a service ? I'm not asking for code here...

Comment: And where you store your business  logic?)

Comment: @denys281 : in controllers ?

Comment: @Jean no, it is wrong.

Comment: since you can't call a controller from another controller it's recommended to write all the business logic in a service, in order to be able to access that code from every controller you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think a Service like not a real "service" ( as the mailer ) but you have thinking about at the dependency Injection design pattern. So if you have an action named 'enrolledStudentAction()' your controller method should be thin and you have to make "the logic" inside a class named StudentManager. The studentManager do the logic in order to find the enrolled users and return the result to the controller. The controller call the method getEntolledStudent by the service container. Decoupling!

Comment: Ok, this sounds good. But it is not the way the Symfony doc tells us to do, is it ? Is this one way to do it, or is it the only correct approach ?

Comment: Actually this is correct. Let's suppose your application was build with Symfony2 and one day you have to move on Symfony3, services are the ones that will be **reusable**. So, in services you have to put all the business code that has nothing to do with Symfony. Usually a service method receives an Object and returns an Object or true/false. Also, if you have some code what will be called by two differents controller it should be written in a service in order to **don't** write it twice!

Answer (score 4):

All business logic must be in service. According slide number 46 in   [How Kris Writes Symfony Apps](http://www.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/how-kris-writessymfonyappssymfonycon). Thin model, thin controller, fat service layer.

Comment: Well no.  Must is too strong of a word here.